# Suggestions on the trouble I am having with comparing my two dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here's is my original code:

```
import csv
with open ("filename1.txt") as f:
    dict1 = {}
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
    for row in r:

        a, b, v = row
        dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

for key in dict1:
    print(key[0])
    print(key[1])
    print(d[key][0]])
```

This code of course prints which ever column I want. For example here is an example of the text file that it is printing from. I have control over my keys and I can print either column 1, 2, or 3.

```
7   10165876    0.457295035
6   145989671   0.738336666
3   225038504   0.575564389
```

However when I implement this code and try to compare two dictionaries, I no longer have control over my keys and I get an error:

```
import csv
with open ("filename1.txt") as f:
   dict1 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:

       a, b, v = row
       dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

  #for key in dict1:
       #print(key[0])
       #print(key[1])
       #print(d[key][0]])

with open ("filename2.txt") as f:
   dict2 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:

      a, b, v = row
      dict2.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

  #for key in dict2:
     #print(key[0])

   count = 0
   for key in dict1:
       for key in dict2:
           if (dict1[0] == dict2[0]) and abs(dict1[1] - dict2[1]) < 10000:
               count +=1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/MainDict.py", line 29, in <module>
if (dict1[0] == dict2[0]) and abs(dict1[1] - dict2[1]) < 10000:
KeyError: 0
```

I've googled and I understand what the error means, but what does it have to do with my code? As I've mentioned before, in the original code I was not getting a KeyError. But now when I have placed everything together I do.

Why am I getting a KeyError and how can I alter my code and fix it?

Comment: where did you add the key `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key in dict1:
   for key in dict2:
       if (dict1[0] == dict2[0]) and abs(dict1[1] - dict2[1]) < 10000:
           count +=1
```

You are using `key` as the iterator variable for both loops. So you essentially overwrite the variable from the outer loop (`dict1`), making its value inaccessible. Use two *different* names.

Also, inside the loop body, you are using *constant* keys to access elements within your dictionaries. This is completely unlike to your original example where you used `key` to access the dictionary value (using `dict1[key]`) and where you printed the key parts (`key[0]` and `key[1]`). So use those instead:

```
for key1 in dict1:
   for key2 in dict2:
       if key1[0] == key2[0] and abs(key1[1] - key2[1]) < 10000:
           count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. The variable key is allocated twice and never used. The dictionary is probably read as string and not as number.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the `0` and `1` keys. Check OP’s first code for comparison.

Comment: You are right. Your proposed solution is correct, I just copied the problematic piece of code.